# What's the difference between these snippets of code?

Tags: python

Beginner here so please excuse me if this is really obvious.

The intention of the code I have written is to read my_string backwards, and print all vowels it identifies.

Can anybody explain why my first method here does not work? Instead of printing only the vowels, it prints all characters.

```
for letter in my_string[::-1]:
    if letter == "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u":
        print(letter)
```

Wheras my second method below, does work as intended.

```
for letter in my_string[::-1]:
    if letter in 'aeiou':
        print(letter)
```

What is the logic behind this? My own monkey-brain logic tells me that both methods should work. Thank you.

Comment: letter == "a" or "e"most likely doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: Your two `if`-tests don't do the same thing. To emulate the second method with `or`, code it as `if letter == "a" or letter ==  "e" or letter == "i" or letter == "o" or letter == "u":`.  The expression `"e" or "i" or "o" or "u"` evaluates to `"e"` which counts as `True` in an `if`-test.

Comment: You explained that so well, this really helps my understanding. So only the first part of the statement is evaluated as intended, the other letters become like seperate statements to be evaluated in and of themselves and of course as you say, they exist, therefore they are evaluated as True, thus allowing the printing of each letter to run in the for loop, regardless of vowel status. I completely get it now. Thank you so much. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it the first way you have to change the syntax.

```
for letter in my_string[::-1]:
    if letter == "a" or letter == "e" or letter ==  "i" or letter == "o" or letter == "u":
print(letter)
```

Comment: @Ellie: If this solved your problem, please be sure to mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the gray checkbox to the left of the post. That will signal to the rest of the community that this question has been answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: Ah! Will do that now! Thanks for telling me.